# MDL and ReactJs : Event lost after componentHandler.upgradeDom()

Tags: reactjs, material-design-lite

I use React and when componentHandler.upgradeDom() is called all registred events on elements that are ugraded are lost.

I call componentHandler.upgradeDom() manually on componentDidUpdate.

To avoid this I use react-native-listener or I register the event after calling componentHandler.upgradeDom().

Any better solution ?

Comment: how do you registered events on your elements ? can you use codepen share the example code ? :D

Comment: I can't reproduce in jsfiddle... I will upgrade version on my app and maybe there is no issue

Comment: I confirme with last version of MD there is no lost of events

Comment: I still have the problem with react 0.14.3 and mdl 1.0.6. The layout drawer won't appear if not `upgradeDom()`, after it all events bound before, like  `<a onClick={this.handleClick}>` `<input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleCheck} />`, stop working.

Comment: I use react 0.14.3 and 1.0.6 and it's work better a still have a event not working after ugradeDom (input onChange) but onClick works. For the input I add the event by code after upgradeDom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the last version of material design lite (1.0.6) there is no losing of events when componentHandler.upgradeDom() is called.